# How to sort alphabetically tag_list in act_as_taggable_gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, acts-as-taggable-on

I built podcasts page and installed acts_as_taggable_on gem.

in index page, the page shows all the list of podcast items along with the **tag_list**.

I want to show the **tag_list** in alphabetical order, but it shows as the order of creation.

How can I approach this?

I found a way online and tried but getting an error.(below code)

```
=podcast.tag_list.sort{ |x, y| x.name.upcase <=> y.name.upcase }.join(' | ')

 undefined method `name' for "Two":String
```

[image]

Current working code is `=podcast.tag_list.join(' | ')`

Comment: `podcast.tag_list.sort_by(&:downcase)`? Since `tag_list` seems to return an `Array` of `String`s.

Comment: This works perfectly!